# Real Risk of Bankruptcy after a Lottery Win?

Tags: gambling

There are currently claims that between 30% and 70% percent of lottery winners will go bankrupt.

> Indeed, the Certified Financial Planner Board of Standards says nearly a third of lottery winners declare bankruptcy—meaning they were worse off than before they became rich. [Source: Fortune, By RIC EDELMAN January 15, 2016](http://fortune.com/2016/01/15/powerball-lottery-winners/)

and

> In fact, about 70 percent of people who win a lottery or get a big windfall actually end up broke in a few years, according to the National Endowment for Financial Education. [Source: Clevland.com Jan 14, 2016](https://www.cleveland.com/business/index.ssf/2016/01/why_do_70_percent_of_lottery_w.html)

There is a much older Skeptics post saying it is around 1% [Are people who win the lottery more likely to go bankrupt?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5561/are-people-who-win-the-lottery-more-likely-to-go-bankrupt) (*I think, not sure I followed the answer*) but it mentions lack of studies. Based on current reports there is now evidence available and/or the current claims are without foundation.

What is the Real Risk of Bankruptcy after a Lottery Win?

Does current research support current reported percentages?

Related

- [Are you more likely to be struck by lightning than to win the lottery?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/30232)

Comment: I don't see how this question is any different from the one referenced. Asking a question again isn't going to improve the quality of the answers.

Comment: Have a look at [this relevant meta question](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2739/are-is-this-still-true-questions-permitted), which itself is unfortunately a bit old, about re-asking old questions. Basically, a good suggestion is to try to frame it to take into account both the old answers and the new claims, such as "Is there any new research in the last X years since Y similar question that supports these new, similar claims?"

Comment: @Giter edited accordingly. Note that the answer on the potential dupe is not accepted and has gained a 25 rep increase indicating an offered bounty was not specifically awarded.

Comment: Seems worth noting that the answer on the potential dupe also only concerned $50,000 to $150,000 winners, so it's unclear whether this is relevant to the "extremely big winner" lotteries that have been in the news recently and presumably motivated this question to some extent.